# Play Framework validation: how to override validation messages for validators with parameters?

Tags: validation, playframework

I am trying to add "custom" validation messages for the parameters called in a Controller method, per specific method (not in the global list of messages)

I found how to do that in a simple case, like:

**@Required(message="error.shouldspecifyname") String username**

I wonder if I can do a similar trick with validators having parameters.

So, I would like to convert

**@Equals("passwordRepeat") String password**

to something like

**@Equals("passwordRepeat", message="error.passwordsshouldmatch")**

What's the correct syntax?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in the [Javadocs](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2.4/play/data/validation/Equals.html), `@Equals` accepts the `message` parameter. Thus, you just need to write:

```
@Equals(value="passwordRepeat", message="error.passwordsshouldmatch")
```

(when you only specify one argument in an annotation, it means that you are defining the property `value` of this annotation)